# Why does the variable become undefined in an if statement

Tags: if-statement, undefined, var

Why would the variable n become undefined in the below if statement when it is a global variable?

```
function aisaRev() {
        n=n; //globally n=0 
        console.log(n);
        hover=1;
        rev=2;

       //n counts up to 39 and then becomes undefined when it hits the else statement
        if (n<=aisaArray.length){n++}else{n=0; console.log(n)};
        world();
    }
```

Comment: 1. What is the language? 2. Show the rest of your code.

Comment: I presume javascript is used.. Please don't repeat your global variable in your function.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind

should have been

```
if (n<aisaArray.length -1){n++}else{n=0; console.log(n)};
```

something else was becoming undefined before it hit the else statement